# How to fix sporadic org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In our Selenium tests, we occasionally get

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END. Last 0 characters read:
```

These exceptions occur sporadically in a random single test case among many.

What causes this exception and how to fix it?

---

Additional info from the error message that may be relevant:

```
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'chrome.test.domain', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 
'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-132-generic', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'test-server', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', 
os.version: '5.4.0-132-generic', java.version: '11.0.17'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 
103.0.5060.53, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., 
userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.rGHR0n}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: 
localhost:42853}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, 
pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: 
ws://172.17.0.5:4444/sessio..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.53, se:vnc: 
ws://172.17.0.5:4444/sessio..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: 
ws://172.17.0.5:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: 
{implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and 
notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, 
webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
```

Testing dependencies in pom.xml (note that originally I was using version 3.141.59, now updated to 3.8.0 because of [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/1507), but that didn't help):

```
      <!-- Dependencies for testing. -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>[4.8.0,5.0.0)</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Why 2 sets 1) version: '4.3.0'/java.version: '11.0.15' and 2) version: '3.141.59'/java.version: '11.0.17'? Are you using SeleniumGrid?

Comment: share your dependency pom file, If its a maven project

Comment: @ZakariaShahed I did, please check.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I must admit I have no idea. 2) is from pom, but 1) I'm not sure - is it the Chrome browser's version? Tests run on a Linux machine that connects to a Chrome in docker (selenium/standalone-chrome). No grid.

Comment: I've updated Selenium to version 4.8.0 to see if that fixes it, but I'm still getting these exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that the error message `Expected to read a START_MAP but instead have: END` is caused by a page that was loaded okay, but then changed (due to some JavaScript perhaps), and Selenium's internal map does match the DOM any more. It actually looks like it's suddenly turned into an empty page. So this is may the same cause as with the `StaleElementReferenceException`, but it happens even before the element has been found.

Or maybe it's something completely different.

However, while I haven't really found out the root cause, I have found a way to successfully work around the problem. When the `WebDriverException` occurs, it turned out to be a successful approach to start over from loading the page.

I therefore created a wrapper function that would `try` and `catch` the `WebDriverException`, then wait a second and try again. In my tests, it was always enough to retry just once.

Simple example:

```
    public void normalLogin() {
        driver.get(getBaseUrl() + location);
        driver.findElement(By.id("password").sendKeys(getPassword());
        driver.findElement(By.id("authenticateButton").click();
    }

    public void stableLogin() {
        try {
            normalLogin();
        }
        catch (WebDriverException driverE) {
            System.err.println("Caught a WebDriverException, retrying");
            // wait a little 
            try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            // then try again
            normalLogin();
        }
    }
```

Note that the second attempt won't be caught any more, because I haven't had a case where repeating only once wouldn't haven been enough.